# SVG: drawing path from top to bottom of page while scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animate

I need animate SVG paths from top to bottom of the page while scrolling. The main problem is my animation doesn't draw from top to bottom but from start to end point of the path. It should draw along the SVG height. I don't have any idea how to do it. Here is what I have now: [example of my current script on codepen](https://codepen.io/chezirish/pen/dmMdmL)

But I need something like this: [right example](https://bl.ocks.org/sxywu/cdff7e8538477e7222b8) or this: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/idvoh)

```
does anyone have any suggestion on how to accomplish this?
```